# How can I delete macros from a single file from a Excel sheet?

Tags: c#, excel, vba

**Scope:**

Me and my team are developing an Excel Report for our costumer, using VBA. There are Functions and Macros in this .xlms file that I don't want to make available for the customer.

We've managed to delete all the macros from the workbook by using this code sample:

```
 private void DeleteMacros (string reportPath)
    {
        // WorkBookManager is our own Wrapper for the Excel Workbook class
        WorkbookManager wb = new WorkbookManager (reportPath);
        wb.OpenWorkbook (false);

        //Lock workbook
        wb.RunMacro("ThisWorkbook.LockWorkbook");

        //Deleting the Macros from the workbook
        VBProject project = wb.GetInstance().VBProject;

        for (int i = project.VBComponents.Count; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            VBComponent component = project.VBComponents.Item(i);

            try
            {
                project.VBComponents.Remove(component);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }

        for (int i = project.VBComponents.Count; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            VBComponent component = project.VBComponents.Item(i);
            component.CodeModule.DeleteLines(1, component.CodeModule.CountOfLines);
        }

        wb.CloseAndSave();
        wb.CleanUp();
    }
```

**The Problem:**

There are some macros in this workbook that we will still need, like ones used to navigate from one sheet to another, that we binded to buttons ( to avoid showing the sheet tabs at the botton of the report).

**Question:**

Is there any way I can encapsulate those not important(/sensitive) macros in a single file on a single workbook and, somehow, delete all the other workbooks and their macros?

If not, which is the right way to do so?

Comment: Why don't you instead put the code you're currently trying to delete into a separate workbook and have it operate on the report workbook?

Comment: I thought about it, but i just dont know how to delete a single workbook macro from the report. The above code cleans the content of all workbooks of the report including the default "ThisWorkbook"

Comment: Have you tried checking the properties (such as `Name`) of each of `component` before deleting it?  Just don't remove the ones you want to keep...

Comment: No i haven't, but i will try it

Comment: @TimWilliams Feel free to post your solution as a answer so i can pick it

Comment: Do you need to delete all macros or just a few.  If all then just save it as a xlsx which removes the macros for you.  You need to have access to the VB Object Model in order to manipulate the VB Editor and remove macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried checking the properties (such as `Name`) of each of component before deleting it? Just don't remove the ones you want to keep.